# AngularJs why is object undefined on ng-disabled function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeerror

VIEW:

I have a rows repeating , with a save button on each row to save each object individually. I want this button to be disabled if no changes have been made.

```
<tr ng-repeat="option in options | filter:search">
    <a ng-click="save(option)" ng-disabled="isUnchanged(option)">Save</a>
</tr>
```

CONTOLLER:

So I pass the option object to the function, I get its index position in the array. Then compare this 'option' object to its original self in apiKeyOptions[index] which is injected as a service.

```
angular.module('PartOfApp')
.controller('PartOfAppCtrl', function( $scope, ... apiKeyOptions) {

 $scope.options = apiKeyOptions;

 $scope.isUnchanged = function(option) {
       var index = $scope.options.indexOf(option);
       //compare object to the original 
       if(option.value == apiKeyOptions[index].value && apiKeyOptions[index].setting == option.setting){
            //then no changes have been made to this 
            return true;
       }else{
            return false;
       }
```

For some reason I get a console of 100's of errors when any data is changed, saying that the apiKeyOptions[index].value and apiKeyOptions[index].setting are undefind.

The app works perfectly as it should returning true if they are the same but still throws a

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

on apiKeyOptions[index]

if I console.log(apiKeyOptions[index].value) I get no undefined values and all log correctly.

Im guessing Im breaking some angular rules, if anyone could help that would be great.

**apiKeyOptions overview:**

apiKeyOptions is an array of up to 50 objects

each object is in the form

```
{
defaultValue: boolean,
description: null,
name: String,
setting: "Default" or Boolean,
value: Boolean
}
```

**Added after comment below:**
If I add-

```
console.log(index);
console.log(apiKeyOptions[index]);
```

to the function $scope.isUnchanged, I get the expected results 
example :

```
 13
 Object {name: "LOREM IPSUM", description: null, defaultValue: false, setting: "default", value: false…}
```

So index is not always -1. The reason I pass the object to the function and not $index is because of the filter | search so the index will change depending on the search.

**FIXED**

As shown in the answer below . I was getting a index = -1 error but its was buried in 100's of CORRECT log outputs.

Oddly this did not stop the app from working and I will need to have a deeper look into how ng-disabled is bound to a value. To fix I simply replaced the indexOf with

```
for (var i = 0; i< $scope.options.length; i++ ){
            if($scope.options[i].name == option.name){
                var index = i;
            }
       }
```

Comment: can you show a sample of apiKeyOptions. It will help in understanding your problem correctly.

Comment: @ashfaq.p example in edited above

Comment: Is the index in the bounds of the array? 
Is the array undefined or the only undefined when querying by index?

I suspect that the option being passed in to the function is not the same object as the one in the array and so indexOf is returning an invalid index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the parameter passed to `$scope.isUnchanged = function(option) {`
Since ng-repeat creates a new scope for each loop, i suspect that the 'option' available to each loop would be a new object and will not have a reference to 'options' array.

```
<tr ng-repeat="option in options | filter:search">
```

Therefore your `isUnchanged` function will receive parameter as a new object and hence below code always returns -1. Because **indexOf** matches the given argument in the array and since the argument 'option' is an object and doesn't refer(reference comparison) the same element of array hence no match will found. i.e `var a = {id:1};var b = [a]; b.indexOf({id:1}) === -1; b.indexOf(a) === 0;`

```
var index = $scope.options.indexOf(option);//always be -1 in your case
// therefore apiKeyOptions[index] will always be undefined
```

As a workaround you should pass **$index** to `isUnchanged` from the view.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont think this is the case. If I 
console.log(index); 
console.log(apiKeyOptions[index]);
Then I get the correct results 
e.g. 10 & object

Comment: Buried in my console errors was some index = -1. So you were correct. However this only seemed to occur once and didn't stop the app from working correctly. ODD.

Comment: @AidanGee yes you are right, it requires some more retrospection. Thats why i used the statement 'i suspect ...' in answer.